# Javascript coding: Input a specific date, Output the season

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I a very new to Javascript and I need to make a code that allows someone to enter a date and it will result in the season that date is in. I am at a loss at what I should do, an if else statement? This is as far as I got, thank you for everyone's time!

```
<body>
<h1>Date to Season</h1>
<p align="left">Enter Date:
<input id="season" maxlength="4" size="24"/>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submit()"/><br/>
<textarea cols="40" rows="3" id="output"></textarea></body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Submit(){
var date = document.getElementById('season').value;
var seasons = 

if (
```

Comment: How do you expect the data to be typed? MM/DD?

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried to implement this ?

Comment: Although an if statement is easy, working out the season is not so easy without knowing where the user is in. You'd need to use geolocation or geoIP to first find out whether the user is in e.g. Ireland or Australia

Comment: Also, have you considered type=date in your input element (for browsers that support it)?

Comment: I suppose MM/DD and I haven't really implemented this, I'm more at a loss at which direction I should take to code this. I'm very beginner, so I'm not exactly sure as to how to start this? Should I put the dates into an array? Or if/else? I'm sorry if this is really unspecific

Comment: tagawa - I think geolP is too advanced for what I'm trying to do? I just want to be able to enter a date and get the season that date is in.

Comment: The trouble is seasons are different depending on where the user is. When it's winter in the northern hemisphere it's summer in the southern hemisphere, and tropical areas don't have four seasons - only wet and dry.

Comment: tagawa - hmm, you're totally right, but my teacher never specified on the location of the user. I guess since I'm doing this in the United States, he would want it to be based off our location. Also, is it possible to enter a full date (MM/DD/YYYY) and get the season, or can I only enter the month?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note, there are saner ways of doing this (for instance, using a date object for instance), that would probably be more useful/flexible, especially if you want to determine by the actual season start/stop date (March 28th, for example). This is just to demonstrate a starting point.

Here's a very simple example, using a swtich() to return a season according to a numeric month:

http://jsfiddle.net/RtC58/

```
<form name="date">
 <input type="text" name="month"/>
 <input type="button" value="Season?" onClick="getSeason()"/>
</form>

function getSeason() {
    month = document.forms.date.month.value;
    season = '';
    switch(month) {
        case '12':
        case '1':
        case '2':
            season = 'winter';
        break;
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
            season = 'spring';
        break;
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
            season = 'summer';
        break;
        case '9':
        case '10': 
        case '11':
            season = 'fall';
        break;
    }
    alert(season);
}
```

Here's a little bit more complex example, showing the short/long month plus the numeric month.

http://jsfiddle.net/RtC58/1/

```
function getSeason() {
    month = document.forms.date.month.value.toLowerCase();
    season = 'unknown';
    switch(month) {
        case 'dec':
        case 'december':
        case '12':
        case 'jan':
        case 'january':
        case '1':
        case 'feb':
        case 'february':
        case '2':
            season = 'winter';
        break;
        case 'mar':
        case 'march':
        case '3':
        case 'apr':
        case 'april':
        case '4':
        case 'may':
        case '5':
            season = 'spring';
        break;
        case 'jun':
        case 'june':
        case '6':
        case 'jul':
        case 'july':
        case '7':
        case 'aug':
        case 'august':
        case '8':
            season = 'summer';
        break;
        case 'sep':
        case 'september':
        case '9':
        case 'oct':
        case 'october':
        case '10':
        case 'nov':
        case 'november':
        case '11':
            season = 'fall';
        break;
    }
    alert(season);
}
```

A little bit different approach could be to create variables for the seasons, use if/else statements (as the OP wants an example of) and find the 'index of' the month value in the one of the variables (note I added a `,` [comma] to the end of the month to disambiguate 1 from 12 and 1 from 0, etc...).

http://jsfiddle.net/RtC58/3/

```
function getSeason() {
    month = document.forms.date.month.value.toLowerCase()+",";
    winter = 'dec,december,jan,january,feb,february,12,1,2,';
    spring = 'mar,march,apr,april,may,3,4,5,';
    summer = 'jun,june,jul,july,aug,august,6,7,8,';
    fall = 'sep,september,oct,october,nov,november,9,10,11,';
    season = 'unknown';
    if (winter.indexOf(month) != -1) {
        season = 'winter';
    } else if (spring.indexOf(month) != -1) {
        season = 'spring';
    } else if (summer.indexOf(month) != -1) {
        season = 'summer';
    } else if (fall.indexOf(month) != -1) {
        season = 'fall';
    }
    alert(season);
}
```

Comment: Jared Farrish - Thanks a lot! That's what I was trying to do, but I was wondering if I could have put the month numbers into an if/else statement? Such as
function Submit(){
var date = document.getElementById('season').value;
var dateSeasons = 

if (date = 12,1,2 ){
alert("Summer")
}
document.getElementById("output").value= "It is" +dateSeasons;
}
</script>

Comment: As with all such problems, there are many solutions. If you want to accurately determine the seaon where a user is located, then you have some work to do even if you let the user input their location (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season). If you just want a simplistic guide for North America (which I suspect is all you want), then Jared's answer is probably sufficient.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help and patience to explain things, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Jared Farrish - Thank you for taking the time to give me these examples, you've made it a lot clearer to me!

Comment: @Lala - No problem. If you consider it the answer to your question, please click the outline checkmark to the left of the answer (below the vote tally).

Answer (score 25):

No doubt calculating solstices and equinoxes is not what you had in mind, but they are not too difficult.

Contrary to what some have said, solstices and equinoxes do not depend on where you are, though their names do- winter is called summer by somebody on half the globe.

```
Date.fromJulian= function(j){
    j= (+j)+(30.0/(24*60*60));
    var A= Date.julianArray(j, true);
    return new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, A));
}
Date.julianArray= function(j, n){
    var F= Math.floor;
    var j2, JA, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, z;
    j+= .5;
    j2= (j-F(j))*86400.0;
    z= F(j);
    f= j-z;
    if(z< 2299161) a= z;
    else{
        g= F((z-1867216.25)/36524.25);
        a= z+1+g-F(g/4);
    }
    b= a+1524;
    c= F((b-122.1)/365.25);
    d= F(365.25*c);
    e= F((b-d)/30.6001);
    h= F((e< 14)? (e-1): (e-13));
    var JA= [F((h> 2)? (c-4716): (c-4715)),
    h-1, F(b-d-F(30.6001*e)+f)];
    var JB= [F(j2/3600), F((j2/60)%60), Math.round(j2%60)];
    JA= JA.concat(JB);
    if(typeof n== 'number') return JA.slice(0, n);
    return JA;
}
Date.getSeasons= function(y, wch){
    y= y || new Date().getFullYear();
    if(y<1000 || y> 3000) throw y+' is out of range';
    var Y1= (y-2000)/1000, Y2= Y1*Y1, Y3= Y2*Y1, Y4= Y3*Y1;
    var jd, t, w, d, est= 0, i= 0, Cos= Math.degCos, A= [y],
    e1= [485, 203, 199, 182, 156, 136, 77, 74, 70, 58, 52, 50, 45, 44, 29, 18, 17, 16, 14, 12, 12, 12, 9, 8],
    e2= [324.96, 337.23, 342.08, 27.85, 73.14, 171.52, 222.54, 296.72, 243.58, 119.81, 297.17, 21.02,
    247.54, 325.15, 60.93, 155.12, 288.79, 198.04, 199.76, 95.39, 287.11, 320.81, 227.73, 15.45],
    e3= [1934.136, 32964.467, 20.186, 445267.112, 45036.886, 22518.443,
    65928.934, 3034.906, 9037.513, 33718.147, 150.678, 2281.226,
    29929.562, 31555.956, 4443.417, 67555.328, 4562.452, 62894.029,
    31436.921, 14577.848, 31931.756, 34777.259, 1222.114, 16859.074];
    while(i< 4){
        switch(i){
            case 0: jd= 2451623.80984 + 365242.37404*Y1 + 0.05169*Y2 - 0.00411*Y3 - 0.00057*Y4;
            break;
            case 1: jd= 2451716.56767 + 365241.62603*Y1 + 0.00325*Y2+ 0.00888*Y3 - 0.00030*Y4;
            break;
            case 2: jd= 2451810.21715 + 365242.01767*Y1 - 0.11575*Y2 + 0.00337*Y3 + 0.00078*Y4;
            break;
            case 3: jd= 2451900.05952 + 365242.74049*Y1 - 0.06223*Y2 - 0.00823*Y3 + 0.00032*Y4;
            break;
        }
        var t= (jd- 2451545.0)/36525,
        w= 35999.373*t - 2.47,
        d= 1 + 0.0334*Cos(w)+ 0.0007*Cos(2*w);
        est= 0;
        for(var n= 0; n<24; n++){
            est += e1[n]*Cos(e2[n]+(e3[n]*t));
        }
        jd+= (0.00001*est)/d;
        A[++i]= Date.fromJulian(jd);
    }
    return wch && A[wch]? A[wch]: A;
}
Math.degRad= function(d){
    return (d*Math.PI)/180.0
}
Math.degSin= function(d){
    return Math.sin(Math.degRad(d))
}
Math.degCos= function(d){
    return Math.cos(Math.degRad(d))
}
```

Comment: This is madness. I mean, literally. Delightful. +1

Comment: Beautiful thanks a lot. It's a little hard to understand though, the single letter variable names make it a little hard to follow.

Comment: I threw together a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kynbvpLf/3/). Hope it saves someone a little time.

Comment: I would be really helpful if you could add meaningful names to the variables.

Comment: How does this math cause you to find the current season? Are you sure ALL of it is completely relevant?

Comment: "not too difficult" I think this statement is wrong when looking at the code.. Lol

Answer (score 16):

Here's a one-liner.

```js
const getSeason = d => Math.floor((d.getMonth() / 12 * 4)) % 4

console.log('Southern hemisphere (Summer as Dec/Jan/Feb etc...):')
console.log(['Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter', 'Spring'][getSeason(new Date())])

console.log('Northern hemisphere (Winter as Dec/Jan/Feb etc...):')
console.log(['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'][getSeason(new Date())])
```

Comment: This one-liner doesn't work because I'm in the northern hemisphere and it outputs Autumn =(

Comment: @MihaiCiobanu - it all depends on what you mean by 'season'. January-March is often thought of as Winter, but to use say the solstice/equinox you have to look at specific dates, similarly for what various national Met offices define as 'Winter' etc.

Answer (score 8):

Customizable seasons, can do the following:

- astronomical
- meteorological
- 6 seasons
- any natural number

Note that months are 0 (Jan) to 11 (Dec).

```js
const md = (month, day) => ({month, day})
const toMd = date => md(date.getMonth(), date.getDate())

const before = (md1, md2) => (md1.month < md2.month) 
  || ((md1.month === md2.month) && (md1.day <= md2.day)) 

const after = (md1, md2) => !before(md1, md2)

const between = (mdX, mdLow, mdHigh) => 
  after(mdX, mdLow) && before(mdX, mdHigh)
 
const season = (date, seasons) => ((md = toMd(date)) =>
  Object.keys(seasons).find(season => seasons[season](md))
)()

const MARCH_EQUINOX = md(2, 20)
const JUNE_SOLSTICE = md(5, 21)
const SEPTEMBER_EQUINOX = md(8, 23)
const DECEMBER_SOLSTICE = md(11, 21)
const NEW_YEAR = md(0, 1)

const seasons = {
  spring: d => between(d, MARCH_EQUINOX, JUNE_SOLSTICE),
  summer: d => between(d, JUNE_SOLSTICE, SEPTEMBER_EQUINOX),
  fall: d => between(d, SEPTEMBER_EQUINOX, DECEMBER_SOLSTICE),
  winter: d => 
    between(d, DECEMBER_SOLSTICE, NEW_YEAR) ||
    between(d, NEW_YEAR, MARCH_EQUINOX)
}

console.log(
  'It is currently', 
  season(new Date(), seasons),
  'in northern hemisphere on 4 season astronomical calendar'
)
```

Comment: How about the lunar calendar seasons for asian seasons ?

Comment: Should work with the correct "seasons" object. Feel free to contribute.

Comment: @DevonDahon funny guy. 
const months = ["Rat", "Chicken", "Pig", "Crocodile", "Gorilla", "Elephant", "Snake", "Dragon", "Cucumber", "Octopus", "Fish", "Big Foot"];
const asianMonth = months[Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length)];

console.log("Chinese Month", asianMonth);

Comment: note there's a bug in this solution: if you run this for a date between dec solstice and new year you will get "undefined", because the month-day math fails checking that, for example, (11,30) is less than (0, 1), since `before` is a basic number comparison. a simple fix is to just add a 13th month new year md of (12, 1) and use that in the first winter-season range, effectively: `winter: (d) => between(d, DECEMBER_SOLSTICE, md(12, 1)) || ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just split the season that crosses newyear:

```
const seasons = [{
    name: 'Spring',
    start: new Date(2000, 2, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 5, 20)
},{
    name: 'Summer',
    start: new Date(2000, 5, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 8, 20)
},{
    name: 'Autumn/Fall',
    start: new Date(2000, 8, 21),
    end: new Date(2000, 11, 20)
},{
    name: 'Winter',
    start: new Date(2000, 11, 21),
    end: new Date(2001, 2, 20)
}];

/** Checks if a date is within a specified season */
function checkSeason(season, date) {
    let remappedStart = new Date(2000, season.start.getMonth(), season.start.getDate());
    let remappedDate = new Date(2000, date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
    let remappedEnd = new Date(2000, season.end.getMonth(), season.end.getDate());
    
    // Check if the season crosses newyear
    if (season.start.getFullYear() === season.end.getFullYear()) {
        // Simple comparison
        return (remappedStart <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= remappedEnd);
    } else {
        // Split the season, remap all to year 2000, and perform a simple comparison
        return (remappedStart <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= new Date(2000, 11, 31))
        || (new Date(2000, 0, 1) <= remappedDate) && (remappedDate <= remappedEnd);
    }
}

function findSeason(seasons, date) {
    for (let i = 0; i < seasons.length; i++) {
        let isInSeason = checkSeason(seasons[i], date);
        if (isInSeason === true) {
            return seasons[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pieterjandc/L3prwqmh/1/