# Get current weather season by location?

Tags: javascript, weather-api

This might be a long shot but I'm trying to find an API that gets the current weather season (simply Summer, Spring, Winter or Autumn) by location. I know there are numerous APIs to get the current weather, so far I can't find one that returns the current season as well.

We have an svg which will change the colour scheme according to the season. We'd like this to be by location as well so if you're in England and it's Winter, a user in Australia would get a Summer colour scheme.

**UPDATE**

I've just found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671172/1275525) on a question in case someone stumbles on this question.

Comment: Seems like this would be pretty easy to define.  You have 2 sequences of 4 seasons.  Hard-coding them should be fine, I wouldn't expect them to change.  The location difference is just a matter of positive or negative latitude, so if you can get that value then you have what you need.  Unless I'm mistaken and seasonal changes are different in various political regions?  That seems pretty silly.  Hard-coding solstice/equinox dates seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: @David: Seasons around the globe are actually more complicated than 2 sequences of 4 seasons. Take a look at this wiki article as a primer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season Note that some locales count 2 seasons and some 6. But the data may not be so complicated that it cannot be defined per country. I think that wiki article provides a lot of info to get started on defining seasons for different areas of the globe.

Comment: @David I thought about that, maybe I'm getting to technical here, as I've mentioned this is just for a colour scheme nothing more and most of the visitors on the website will be local...we thought it would be a nice feature to have, but there are some countries that tend to have 'less' seasons due to their location.

thanks for that Paul, will look into it :)

Comment: @j.grima: Since it's just for a nice decorative touch, I imagine it doesn't need to be *100%* accurate on the official seasons.  Though it would be kind of cool to progressively build in more accuracy and more features and make this your own open source library :)

Comment: yep true, our focus is definitely locally so if we use dates it should be enough, if it's possible we'll try 'improving it', thanks again :)