# Changing a date string into a season

Tags: javascript

I need to write a JavaScript code that changes a date string (2018-05-20) into a season. I've been using this post as a reference, but when I enter the full date it doesn't work.

[Javascript coding: Input a specific date, Output the season](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670678/javascript-coding-input-a-specific-date-output-the-season)

Any suggestions would be really appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: What is not working ? where you are facing problem ?

Comment: Can you please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the post you provided converts a month into a season, it doesn't understand how to deal with a date string.

In order for your code to deal with a date string, you need to find a way to extract the date from your date string. One way of doing this is by using the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) ADT. The date class has many methods associated with it. One is [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). This will allow you to get the month from your string. However, the `getMonth()` method returns an integer (where January = 0 and December = 12). Thus, you need to add 1 to your date. You also need to convert your number to a string for your switch statement's cases. You can do this by using `.toString()` on your calculate month.

See working example below:

```js
function getSeason() {
  var date = new Date(document.forms.date.month.value);
  var month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();

  var season = '';
  switch (month) {
    case '12':
    case '1':
    case '2':
      season = 'winter';
      break;
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
      season = 'spring';
      break;
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
      season = 'summer';
      break;
    case '9':
    case '10':
    case '11':
      season = 'fall';
      break;
  }
  alert(season);
}
```

```html
<form name="date">
  <input type="text" name="month" value="2018-05-20" />
  <input type="button" value="Season?" onClick="getSeason()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're referencing requires a numerical month value to be passed in, not the whole date string. The simplest thing to do would be to specify the date format you want and then parse it yourself using something like split().

Working example using the date format you provided with '2018-05-20'.

```js
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function(){
         var month = document.getElementById('date').value.split('-')[1];
        getSeason(month);

      })
       

  function getSeason(month) {
      var season = '';
      switch(month) {
          case '12':
          case '01':
          case '02':
              season = 'winter';
          break;
          case '03':
          case '04':
          case '05':
              season = 'spring';
          break;
          case '06':
          case '07':
          case '08':
              season = 'summer';
          break;
          case '09':
          case '10': 
          case '11':
              season = 'fall';
          break;
      }
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=season
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date">
<button id="button" type="button">Submit</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```