# Get the next or last occurrence of a day and month based on today's date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to determine whether I'm in the Spring, Summer or Autumn period of any given year, and display the a journal based on that. The periods are as follows:

```
Spring: 14th January - 6th May 
Summer: 7th May - 7th October
Autumn: 8th October - 13th January
```

So today (7th February), I'm in the Spring period (14th January 2019 - 6th May 2019) and showing the Spring 2019 issue. However, let's say it's Christmas Day 2019. I'll be in Autumn period (8th October 2019 - 13th January 2020) so I'll be showing the Autumn 2019 issue, which means the next Spring and Summer issues will be in 2020.

I've been messing around with JS dates and moment objects to try and establish the current/next periods based on today, and I would post my code here but I'm almost sure it's all useless. It the change of year over the Autumn period which is tripping me up. Does anyone have any libraries or suggestions that might help? Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: You must live in Camelot, there is no winter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080378/check-if-one-date-is-between-two-dates-javascript). Just pass in the current season object and today's date (which can be a simple `var date = new Date()`). There arent any libraries I know of that give you seasonal dates automatically. You'll have to add some kind of code that runs on a schedule or executes during a specific season each year to update or rebuild the date objects so that they have the correct year.

If you're looking for more complicated a way of doing this without having to update the dates check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670678/javascript-coding-input-a-specific-date-output-the-season)

```
var spring = {};
spring.startDate = "02/01/2019"
spring.endDate = "02/09/2019"
var today = "02/07/2019"

function checkSeason(season, currentDate) {
  console.log(season.startDate)
  console.log(currentDate)

  var d1 = season.startDate.split("/");
  var d2 = season.endDate.split("/");
  var c = currentDate.split("/");

  var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1, d1[0]); // -1 because months are from 0 to 11
  var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1, d2[0]);
  var check = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1]) - 1, c[0]);

  if (check > from && check < to) {
    console.log("its in the season")
  }
}


checkSeason(spring, today)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a super simple solution, with no libraries. Works for your problem as is and for all future years, only if the dates are the same every year.

If you planned to have many more issues per year and run this multiple times constantly, then this could be rewritten differently.

```
// you can completely ignore autumn because if it's not spring or summer it will be Autumn. 
// But I still put it to 2019 just in case you planned to use it with this method.
let issues = { "Spring": [new Date(2019, 0, 14), new Date(2019, 4, 6)],
               "Summer": [new Date(2019, 4, 7), new Date(2019, 9, 7)],
               "Autumn": [new Date(2019, 9, 8), new Date(2019, 0, 13)]
             }

// today is the day we are trying to find the correct issue for.
// Any date can be put here, just setFullYear to 2019, 2019 is arbitrary
let today = new Date().setFullYear(2019); 

// console.log the appropriate issue for today
if (issues.Summer[0] <= today && issues.Summer[1] >= today) {
    console.log("Summer");
} else if (issues.Spring[0] <= today && issues.Spring[1] >= today) {
    console.log("Spring");
} else {
    console.log("Autumn");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sam said, you can avoid the year rollover by just comparing the other seasons for the current year. If it's not one of the others, it must be the roll over one.

```js
function getSeason(d) {
  // Default to today's date
  d = d || new Date();
  // Zero time part for comparison
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  // Use the current year for comparisons
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  // Default season if others fail
  var season = 'Autumn';
  // Data for seasons, use ECMAScript month numbering
  var seasons = [
    {name: 'Spring', 
     start: [0, 14],  // Jan 14
     end: [4, 6]},    // May 06
    {name: 'Summer',
     start: [4, 7],   // May 07
     end: [9, 7]}     // Oct 07
  ];
  
  // Set season
  seasons.forEach(s => {
    let sStart = new Date(year, ...s.start);
    let sEnd = new Date(year, ...s.end);
    if (d >= sStart && d <= sEnd) {
      season = s.name;
    }
  })
  return season;
}

console.log('Today is : ' + getSeason());

[new Date(2019,0, 1), // 1 Jan Autumn
 new Date(2019,0,21), // 21 Jan Spring
 new Date(2019,5,30)  // 30 Jun Summer
].forEach(d => {
  console.log(d.toDateString()+ ': ' + getSeason(d));
});
```

The code can be more concise using newer features:

```js
function getSeason(d = new Date()) {
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let year = d.getFullYear();
  let seasons = [
    {name: 'Spring', start: [0, 14], end: [4, 6]},
    {name: 'Summer', start: [4, 7], end: [9, 7]}
  ];      
  return (seasons.find(s => d >= new Date(year, ...s.start) && d <= new Date(year, ...s.end)) || {name:'Autumn'}).name;
}

console.log('Today is : ' + getSeason());

[new Date(2019,0, 1), // 1 Jan Autumn
 new Date(2019,0,21), // 21 Jan Spring
 new Date(2019,5,30)  // 30 Jun Summer
].forEach(d => {
  console.log(d.toDateString()+ ': ' + getSeason(d));
});
```