# Conditional statement - determing season

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am doing an excercise to determine the season based on specifically provided date. Below is my code and it works, but there must be a better way...
I would like to use conditional statement for my solution.
Input is:

- month as a string
- date as a number

**Season    Start Date**
Spring  March 20,
Summer  June 21,
Autumn  September 22,
Winter  December 21

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
let month = 'Dec';
let day = 23;

if(month === 'Apr' || month === 'May') {
    console.log('Spring');
    } else if((day >= 20 && month === 'Mar') || (day < 21 && month === 'Jun')) {
        console.log('Spring');
    } else if(month === 'Jul' || month === 'Aug') {
        console.log("Summer");
    } else if((day >= 21 && month === 'Jun') || (day < 22 && month === 'Sept')){      
        console.log("Summer");
    } else if (month === 'Oct' || month === 'Nov') {
        console.log("Autumn");
    } else if ((day >= 22 && month === 'Sept') || (day < 21 && month === 'Dec')) {
        console.log("Autumn");
    } else if (month === 'Oct' || month === 'Nov') {
        console.log("Winter");
    } else if((day >= 21 && month === 'Dec') || (day < 20 && month === 'Mar')){
        console.log("Winter");
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript coding: Input a specific date, Output the season](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670678/javascript-coding-input-a-specific-date-output-the-season)

Comment: I went through this and from what I could see, the accepted solution as well as some of the rest, do not include information on how to implement the number input in the solution. I've seen there are great more complex solutions, but they seem quite different than what I am trying to achieve :)

Comment: @GeorgiPopov How is the month selected? Is the exercise just providing you with the month in string form or is there going to be a drop-down from which you can select the month?

Comment: Sorry I should have provided that info initially. Just a string form.

Comment: OK - I've updated my code to assume that the month is a 3-character string and the day is a number.  I just construct a string in the format MMDD and do the tests as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert your date into a string in "MMDD" format, you could do:

```js
var months = ["xxx","Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

function getMMDD(mth, dy) {
  return months.indexOf(mth).toString().padStart(2, "0") + dy.toString().padStart(2, "0");
}  

function findSeason(mth, dy) {
  let d = getMMDD(mth, dy);
  if (d < "0320") {return "Winter";}
  if (d < "0621") {return "Spring";}
  if (d < "0921") {return "Summer";}
  if (d < "1222") {return "Autumn";}
  return "Winter";
}

console.log(findSeason("Jan", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Feb", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Mar", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Apr", 28));
console.log(findSeason("May", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Jun", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Jul", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Aug", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Sep", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Oct", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Nov", 25));
console.log(findSeason("Dec", 25));
```

This is just a simple string comparison.  The first test that matches, returns the season.  If no test matches (the last few days in December), then return "Winter".

Comment: Aren't you gonna add the `// convert to string in "MMDD" format` part?

Comment: That would entirely depend on how the month and day parts are determined - they could already be in a Date object or they could be selected by the user or derived from an innerHTML text string.  All the OP showed was "provided date" - that could mean one of many different formats.  If the original format was known then, yes, I could add in a conversion script.

Comment: asked op regarding the question, said string form.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object containing each seasons each seasons end and then find the find first season whose date is larger than the one provided (if not found circle around to the 1st).

The problem with this is that you need to convert "Dec" and 23 into a date object. An easy way to do this is create an array of all the months and whenever you need to find the season get the index of the month on that Array and use it like so `new Date(_year_, _index_, _date_)`.

```js
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var seasons = {
  "Winter": new Date(year, 2, 20),
  "Spring": new Date(year, 5, 21),
  "Summer": new Date(year, 8, 22),
  "Autumn": new Date(year, 11, 21)
};

console.log(getSeason("Jan", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Feb", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Mar", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Apr", 20));
console.log(getSeason("May", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Jun", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Jul", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Aug", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Sep", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Oct", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Nov", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Dec", 20));
console.log(getSeason("Dec", 22));

function getSeason(month, day) {
  var index = months.indexOf(month);
  var newDate = new Date(year, index, day);
  for (var key in seasons) {
    if (newDate < seasons[key]) return key;
  }
  return Object.keys(seasons)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using conditionals that works too (see below). Thanks so much for all suggestions!

```
let month = 'Apr';
let date = 3;

switch (month) {
    case "Mar":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 19) {
            console.log("Winter");
        } else if (date >= 20 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Spring");
            break;
        }
    case "Apr":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 30) {
            console.log("Spring");
            break;
        }
    case "May":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Spring");
            break;
        }
    case "Jun":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 20) {
            console.log("Spring");
        } else if (date >= 21 && date <= 30) {
            console.log("Summer");
            break;
        }
    case "Jul":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Summer");
            break;
        }
    case "Aug":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Summer");
            break;
        }
    case "Sep":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 21) {
            console.log("Summer");
        } else if (date >= 22 && date <= 30) {
            console.log("Autumn");
            break;
        }
    case "Oct":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Autumn");
            break;
        }
    case "Nov":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 30) {
            console.log("Autumn");
            break;
        }
    case "Dec":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 21) {
            console.log("Autumn");
        } else if (date >= 22 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Winter");
            break;
        }
    case "Jan":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 31) {
            console.log("Winter");
            break;
        }
    case "Feb":
        if (date >= 1 && date <= 29) {
            console.log("Winter");
            break;
        }
};
```