# Change background-image of a class dynamically on a date using javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the background image of my homepage depending on the season for example change from spring.jpg to summer.jpg. What I have written so far,

```
var currentDate=="12/01/2020";
if (currentDate==True){
    document.body.background = "spring.jpg";
}else{
    document.body.background = "summer.jpg"; 
}
```

Just wondering how far off I am, and if this is possible

Comment: Do you want to determine the season from a string or from an actual [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Comment: `var currentDate == "12/01/2020";` should be `var currentDate = "12/01/2020";` if you want to declare the variable. `==` is used to compare two values and not to assign a value

Answer (score 0):

please use it like mentioned below it will work for u.

```
var currentDate == "12/01/2020";
if (currentDate == True) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('spring.jpg')"; 
}else { 
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('summer.jpg')"; 
}
```

Comment: This won't work, the syntax is wrong. Try document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('summer.jpg')"; for example.

Comment: my bad .. let me fix the quote issue i am editing my comment.... you can use it now

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible.

I think

1. Define duration of season

   ```
   const SEASONS = {
      SPRING: {fromDate - toDate},
      SUMMER: {fromDate - toDate},
      ...
   }
   ```
2. Check `today` is in what season (switch - case), then apply image by:

`document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('season.png')";`

refer [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of defining what a season is, but for a simple one where 3 months define a season we can use the simple formula given by @omgaz in [Javascript coding: Input a specific date, Output the season](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670678/javascript-coding-input-a-specific-date-output-the-season)

```js
const getSeason = d => Math.floor((d.getMonth() / 12 * 4)) % 4

let IamInTheNorthernHemisphere = true; //change to false if you are in the Southern hemisphere

let seasons = IamInTheNorthernHemisphere ? ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'] : ['Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter', 'Spring'];

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + seasons[getSeason(new Date())] + ".jpg)";
alert(document.body.style.backgroundImage);
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```